# Maximal Subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $M$ be a nontrivial proper subgroup of $G$ with the following conditions:

a) If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $M\lneqq H\lneqq G$, then $H$ contains at least one minimal subgroup of $G$ say $L$, such that $M\cap L=1$.

b) If $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $M\cap K=1$ then $K\cong Z_p$ for some prime $p$.

Can we say that $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$?

Please read my comments after Derek Holt's answer.

Comment: Counterexample: $p$ odd, $G$ the nonabelian group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$, and $M$ its center (of order $p$). Then (a) is trivial (it clerly holds in any group of prime exponent) and (b) is clear since every subgroup of $G$ with order $p^2$ contains the center.

Comment: I think if we add the following condition to the question, then we probably exclude your Counterexample and other similar cases.                                    c) There exists at least one maximal subgroup say $M^{'}$, such that $M\nleq M^{'}$ and $M^{'}$ contains all minimal subgroups of $M$.

Comment: Could you edit your question to make it clear? modifying the question in the comments is confusing. Also opening a bounty for a question ticked as answered is somewhat contradictory.

Comment: The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes. What's wrong? please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: Should I change the original question? I thought that it is dishonestly and also may be confusing for those who read the question for the first time.

Comment: The current answer is perfectly good and only becomes "out-of-date" if you change the question. Which you really shouldn't (especially in comments to the accepted answer), except for adding condition c) (and saying so in a comment) as YCor already asked.

Comment: Constantly moving the goalposts is generally frowned upon across all SE sites.  It's okay to make separate, new questions for each new set of goalposts, though since this is a research-level site you might want to consider the possibility that you do not currently understand whatever motivates your question well enough to know what the correct question to ask is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember answering a very similar (possibly the same) question recently but I cannot find it.

Let $G$ be a central product of a cyclic group $M$ of order $4$ and the dihedral group $D_8$ of order $8$. So $|G|=16$. (In fact you get an isomorphic group if you replace $D_8$ by $Q_8$. A central product of $C_4$ with an extraspecial $2$-group is called a group of *symplectic type*.)

Then all subgroups of $G$ strictly between $M$ and $G$ have order $8$ and are isomorphic to $C_4 \times C_2$, and have the $C_2$ as the required subgroup $L$. But $M$ has no complement in $G$, so any subgroup $K$ with $K \cap M=1$ has order $1$ or $2$. (You need to assume that $K$ is nontrivial in the problem.) This example also satisfies your condition c), since the subgroups $D_8$ (and $Q_8$) are maximal and contain all minimal subgroups of $M$.

You can construct similar examples for any prime $p$ as a central product of $C_{p^2}$ with an extraspecial group of order $p^3$.

Comment: Dear all. After a long check I got some new results which may leads to get a corrected version of this question. Now I invite you all to think of this new version and if possible help me to find a useful result.                                       Let $G$ be a finite group and $L_{1}, L_{2},...,L_{n}$ be a family of minimal subgroups of $G$. Suppose that $M_{1},..., M_{k}$ are the all proper subgroups of $G$ which contain $L_{i}$'s as their minimal subgroups and have not any minimal subgroups other than $L_{i}$'s.

Comment: Also suppose that the following conditions hold for every $M_{j}$, $1\leq j\leq k$: a) If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $M_{j}\lneqq H\lneqq G$, then $H$ contains at least one minimal subgroup of $G$ say $L^{'}$, such that $M_{j}\cap L^{'}=1$.

b) If $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $M_{j}\cap K=1$ then $K\cong Z_p$ for some prime $p$.

Can we say that at least one of the $M_{j}$'s is a maximal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @H.Shahsavari: comments are not meant to modify questions. It is up to you to make your question clear in the question box. In the present case with an accepted answer, it would probably be best to ask another question, with due reference to this one.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner It is starting to look as though this process will go indefinitely: counterexample leads to extra hypotheses.

Comment: َAs it seems, no one want to answer the question and every body want just to blame me. OK keep on nagging.

Comment: @DerekHolt I studied you counterexample carefully and it is clear that your previous example does not work for these conditions. Of course finding a new counterexample will be an interesting challenge. whether you give a counterexample or proof it, I learn a new thing and I think this is the main goal of this website.

Comment: @H.Shahsavari - People are not objecting to using the website to learn a new thing. They are objecting to the form of the use. Good form in your situation is to *ask a new question*, linking back to this one, that adds the added conditions, rather than trying to get people to engage a modification to the question in the comments.

Comment: Here is an example of how to do it: I asked a first question - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/237688/is-the-restriction-of-a-graded-automorphism-of-a-polynomial-ring-to-a-polynomial - which Todd Leason completely answered. Then I asked a new question - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/238103/is-the-restriction-of-a-graded-automorphism-linearizable-in-characteristic-zero - which adds a new condition ruling out the example given in Todd's answer (and another condition). Doing it this way makes it clear that I acknowledge Todd's answer as having answered the question.